# Python Tkinter Calculator wont evaluate text from entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, eval, calculator

I am trying to make a simple calculator app using tkinter, but everytime I run the code below i get an error message saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec(codeObject, __main__.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\csp\Python\Calculator App.py", line 17, in <module>
    solved = eval(expression)
  File "<string>", line 0

   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Calculator')
inp = Entry(tk,text="Enter Expression Here",width=20)
inp.pack()
exit = False
def exitbtn():
    global exit
    exit = True
    return exit
btn = Button(tk,text="Quit?",command=exitbtn)
btn.pack
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=200,height=200)
canvas.pack()
while not exit:
    expression = inp.get()
    solved = eval(expression)
    canvas.create_text(100,100,text=expression,font=('Times', 15))
    canvas.create_text(100,150,text=solved,font=('Times', 15))
    if exit == True:
        break
tk.destroy()
```

i am really new to Python and dont understand why the "solved = eval(expression)" line wont work. please help

Answer (score 2):

So, the reason why `eval` is not working is because when you first start your program, `expression` is just an empty string. If you go to the python shell, and type in `eval('')`, you'll see the same error appear.

One solution would be to check if `expression` is an empty string or not, and do something like this:

```
expression = inp.get()
if expression != '':
    solved = eval(expression)
else:
    solved = '?'
```

However, even after you apply this fix, your program won't work, for unrelated reasons. The primary reason is that you never call `tk.mainloop()` (or whatever it's called), so the window will not show up.

This is because of your `while` loop -- what you wanted to do was to constantly check the input field and update your canvas whenever you get new input after running it through `eval`.

However, GUI programs, in general, don't work that way and require a different mindset and approach while writing them. Instead of writing loops to check and update program state, you write functions that will automatically be called whenever the program state changes (which are called events). It'll feel a bit backwards at first, but over time it'll help make your code cleaner and easier to manage.

You're actually already doing this in one part of your program -- with your `exitbtn` function. Now, you just need to convert your `while` loop into a similar function and bind it to the `Entry` object.

**EDIT:**

Here's some example code that does what you want:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *


# Create the GUI
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Calculator')

inp = Entry(tk, text="Enter Expression Here", width=20)
inp.pack()

btn = Button(tk, text="Quit?")
btn.pack()

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()


# Create callback functions
def end_program(event):
    '''Destroys the window and ends the program without needing
    to use global variables or a while loop'''
    tk.destroy()
    sys.exit() # Automatically ends any Python program

def update_canvas(event):
    '''Gets the input, tries to eval it, and displays it to the canvas'''
    expression = inp.get()
    try:
        solved = eval(expression)
    except SyntaxError: 
        # The expression wasn't valid, (for example, try typing in "2 +")
        # so I defaulted to something else.
        solved = '??'

    canvas.delete('all') # remove old text to avoid overlapping
    canvas.create_text(100, 100, text=expression,font=('Times', 15))
    canvas.create_text(100, 150, text=solved,font=('Times', 15))


# Bind callbacks to GUI elements
btn.bind('<Button-1>', end_program)
inp.bind('<KeyRelease>', update_canvas)


# Run the program
tk.mainloop()
```

Some things to note:

- I moved your code for checking `inp` and writing to the canvas to the `update_canvas` function, and got rid of the `while` loop.
- The `update_canvas` function will automatically be called whenever somebody lets go of a key while typing in the `inp` object (the `<KeyRelease>` event).

  - This can cause some problems -- this will mean your `update_canvas` function will be called while the user is in the process of typing text into your calculator. For example, what if the user types in `2 + 2 *`? It's not a complete expression, so can't be parsed by `eval`.
  - To solve this, I just wrapped `eval` in a try-except to prevent any bad input from mucking up the program.
- Similarly, `end_program` will be called whenever somebody left-clicks on the `btn` object (the `<Button-1>` event).

Comment: what do you mean? do you have a simple example that I could look at to better understand?

Comment: where did you define tk.mainloop?

Comment: @user2155059 What do you mean? I called it at the bottom of the file.

Comment: where did you tell the tk mainloop what to do when you call it is what I mean.

Comment: @user2155059 That would be where I bound the callbacks to the GUI elements (`btn.bind` and `inp.bind`). 

Basically, when I called those two functions, I told `tk.mainloop`: "If I click the button, run the `end_program` function. If I release a key in the input box, call the `update_canvas` button. In the meantime, just wait for something to happen". 

That's basically how GUI programming is usually done: you bind functions to events, then you call the `mainloop` function (which the library provides) and it automatically takes care of things.